# jq convert an array by selecting to a list using only some values of the objects in the array

Tags: json, jq

I have the following object

```
{
  "name": "Papanito",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "Name1",
      "value": "Value1",
      "type": 0,
      "linkedId": null
    },
    {
      "name": "Name2",
      "value": "Value2",
      "type": 0,
      "linkedId": null
    },
    {
      "name": "Name3",
      "value": "Value3",
      "type": 0,
      "linkedId": null
    },
    {
      "name": "Name4",
      "value": "Value3",
      "type": 0,
      "linkedId": null
    }
  ],
}
```

Which I would like to convert in this

```
{
  "name": "Papanito",
  "fields": [
    "Name1": "Value1",
    "Name2": "Value2",
    "Name3": "Value3",
    "Name4": "Value4",
  ],
}
```

I tried several things, but I did not yet figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```bash
jq '.fields |= ( map(.key = .name | del(.type,.linkedId,.name)) | from_entries )' file
```

This updates the `fields` array.  First, for each element (using `map()`), a `key` key is created with the value from the `name` key.  Then the `type`, `linkedId`, and `name` keys are deleted from the element.  We are now left with a `key` and a `value` key in each element of the `fields` array, which is just what `from_entries` needs to associate the `key` values as keys to the `value` values.

Testing on the data given in the question (with a trailing comma removed), this generates the following JSON:

```json
{
  "name": "Papanito",
  "fields": {
    "Name1": "Value1",
    "Name2": "Value2",
    "Name3": "Value3",
    "Name4": "Value3"
  }
}
```

Note that your expected output is invalid JSON, as an array can't have keys.  Therefore, the `fields` value in the output above is an object, not an array.

Would you want to keep `fields` as an array, you could rearrange the operations a bit:

```bash
jq '.fields |= map([.key = .name | del(.type,.linkedId,.name)] | from_entries)' file
```

For the given data (corrected as mentioned above), this would generate something equivalent to the following document:

```json
{
   "name": "Papanito",
   "fields": [
      { "Name1": "Value1" },
      { "Name2": "Value2" },
      { "Name3": "Value3" },
      { "Name4": "Value3" }
   ]
}
```

This has the benefit that two elements with the same original `name` values would not overwrite each other in the result.

---

Conceptually, the above *deletes* the data that we no longer want.  The following variations *extract* the data we want instead.

This generates the last result from above:

```bash
jq '.fields |= map({ (.name): .value })' file
```

And we can get the first result (with `fields` as a single object) by merging the entries in the list:

```bash
jq '.fields |= (map({ (.name): .value }) | add)' file
```